# Azure FrontDoor Priority

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

I have an Azure FrontDoor service set up to distribute traffic toward two API Management services in a Primary / Backup type manner. As in I want all traffic to go to my primary APIM service, and if I happen to turn that one off (faking an outage) then all traffic would go towards my secondary APIM service. Reading the documentation I believe that the only thing I need to set is the Priority levels to be 1 (primary) and 2 (secondary), and if there is any response available from 1 then traffic will be sent there. I am running into an issue where traffic seems to be sent equally to both of my services. I thought that the weighting property would only be considered if evaluating two services that have equal priority (or am I incorrect about this)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are correct the routing chooses top prio first and then weight for the requests. the rules can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-routing-methods)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue. I was able to get Primary/Backup behavior by setting the Primary priority to 1 and the Secondary priority to 5.